# "return someString and partString in someString" in Python3

Tags: python, string, boolean-expression

```py
test1 = "this is test line"  # non-empty string
test2 = ""                   # empty string

def test_line(line):
    return line and not "is" in line

test1_result = test_line(test1)
test2_result = test_line(test2)

print(test1_result)  # True
print(test2_result)  # empty line printed
```

I've seen several ppl using this kind of code for boolean output

```py
return someString and not partString in someString # "not" is optional
```

Why `test2` results in empty line? And by adding `someString` as an argument what additdional function we get compared to just using `partString in someStirng`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second function call with an empty string, when you essentially do

```
return "" and not "is" in ""
```

the `and` expression gets short-circuited due to the first condition evaluating as `False` essentially (you don’t need both conditions to fail for an `and` to fail) and hence it gets returned as an empty string. The second boolean condition won’t be evaluated.

```
>>> bool("")
False
>>> "" and 1 == 1/0
''
>>> False and 1 == 1/0
False
```

But when you do it with a non-empty string, both parts of the boolean expression would be evaluated and thus giving exception, as expected

```
>>> bool("b")
True
>>> "b" and 1 == 1/0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
>>> "b" and 1 == 1
True
```

Comment: Thanks Jarvis. I understand the concept better now, but still tricky that it returns boolean or string - two different types. I thought that the second function call should return `False`, not an empty string. Could you explain why it does not return 'False'?